# SQL/Python (Django) - Join each row to entire table

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm currently creating an application which maps peoples skills against various technologies.
I have 3 tables;

### Employees

- Name
- Department

### Skill

- Skill name

### Results

- Name (FK)
- Skill (FK)
- Skill level

I wish to be able to see every single employee with each skill listed in a table. I believe the correct procedure to retrieve this information would be to perform some sort of for loop and select the info from the 3 tables? The alternative is adding rows to the results table each time an employee or skill is added (although this doesn't seem like correct logic to me).

Comment: Funnily, a very similar case is demonstrated in the Django tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a correct logic. Since you have to keep the **level** of the skill for each employee.
Lets say you have created three models.

Employee
skill 
Result

when you do

## to get the skills of employee with id = 37

```
emp = Employee.objects.get(pk=37)

#here we will get an array which has tuple all the skills and its level for employee
skill_level_array = [(Skill.objects.filter(pk=x.skill), x.level) for x in Result.objects.filter(employee=emp)]
```

## To get skills for all empoyees

```
all_emp = Employee.objects.all()
grand_array = {}
for emp in all_emp:
    skill_level_array = [(Skill.objects.filter(pk=x.skill), x.level) for x in Result.objects.filter(employee=emp)]
    grand_array[emp] = skill_level_array
```

Now grand_array has an array of dictionary, with key as employee and value as array of tuple

Comment: This seems close. However, the problem I have is that the results table doesn't have every single skill against every single employee. For example if I added a new employee then they would have no skills and no results. However, I wish to be able to see their "results" still (Which of course would be null).

Comment: hmmm.. I think what you are talking about has more to do with presentation of data, meaning you have to rely on html, css, javascript for that.

Comment: what you can do is on each addition of new user, create a skill user entry with level 0. This is inefficient but something worth looking into